# Ssh behind static IP

Tags: ssh, git

Sorry if this is duplicated , I just can't find a solution . 
Scenario -

static IP 125.22.25.241 which is accessible from outside world with ssh .

Local ip 10.0.0.6 - local pc inside the netqork of static ip which contains git repository . /home/game/foobar.git

My question is How from external IP address I can use git commands to directly interact with local pc's git repository .
something like this .

```
git push admin@125.22.25.241:/home/game/foobar.git
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. My examples are based on the native Git protocol TCP port `9418`, but the same can be modified for other type repositories, too. If you have a repository using SSH port `22` and it's already taken, you can use ANY external port, instead, with both of these methods.

1. Configure your router perform a **port forward** through the NAT i.e. translate external IP address and port to internal combination e.g. `198.51.100.100:9418 -> 10.0.0.6:9418`. (It seems that configuring a port forward using almost any router is collected in the same place, although there seems to be a lot of ads in [portforward.com](https://portforward.com/router.htm). I'd prefer the User Guide of your device.)
2. Create a **SSH tunnel**:

   ```
   ssh -L 9418:10.0.0.6:9418 user@198.51.100.100
   ```

   ...and use Git through this tunnel:

   ```
   git push admin@127.0.0.1:/home/game/foobar.git
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Get an IPv6 static subnet. Assign a static address to the host and put it in public DNS. Allow git or ssh protocols in your firewall.

Comment: didn't get after two answers really , I was thinking it is a easy task but now I am really confused

Comment: More than one solution to problems exist. In this example, you can get connectivity to the host via network address translation *or* a public IP address.